# Force CK editor to save everything as it is

Tags: fckeditor

I am using CK editor on a text area. It is working fine but there is one problem and it is when I save content it removes some attributes and doesn't recognize all HTML tags. For example it is removing class attribute from ul li and also doesn't recognize many of HTML tags. Is there any way to modify CK editor so as to make to save everything. Removing it is not an option because CK editor is needed to make some customizations if a user is saving text. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the option you are searching for: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#%21/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-allowedContent

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get around this so I found another solution for this which I think might help others in similar situations. I now provide two options (using radio buttons) to users to save their data, through simple text box or through a fully CK editor loaded text box. If a user has already formatted text like containing lots of HTML tags, CSS classes, scripting etc they can simply select simple text box and it will save everything as it is without applying or removing anything. If they need to apply some formatting to simple text they can select loaded text box and format their text.